# from merged dataframe get o/p of both dataframes side by side with difference

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 dataframes(df1,df2), where primary key of a column can be at any index.Once i have the smaller dataframe(tempDf1,tempdf2) from both  with the primary key on a column, i need to check for match of other column values .If there is a mismatch i need to show the data side by side .And if data in df1 missed in df2, it will show dataDf1|NAN

I tried to merge using outer join and get the data which is missed in df1 or df2 .The result provides me right_only or left_only.Now i need to get the result such that i have the side by side differences.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5,19],
    ['a', 51,191],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['c', 24, 9],
    ['a', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['a', 51,191],
    ['c', 4, 9],
    ['a', 5, 19]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])

merged=df1.merge(df2, indicator=True,how='outer')
merged[merged['_merge']=='left_only']
merged=merged.loc[merged['_merge'].str.contains("_only")]
print merged
```

Actual results:

```
name attr11 attr12  _merge
c     24      9   left_only
c      4      9  right_only
a     24      9   left_only
```

Expected result ->prints only the differences:

```
name  attr11_df1  attr11_df2  attr12_df1  attr12_df2
c         24         4           9            9
a         24         NAN         9            NAN
```

And highlight the differences in color

Comment: Considering Primary key as "name" column

Comment: Any possible solution

Comment: I am looking for an answer,  can someone put some insight